# Recognize when a notification posted / removed is in a group

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-statusbar

I'm trying to play with [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) for check if StatusBarNotifications (displayed in StatusBar) are inherent to a group (ex. mails or messages). I'm using sdk >= 21.

Playing with applications well-known like fb, whatsapp or gmail I saw different rules for marking grouped messages (group and key properties - of [StatusBarNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html) - are not so easy to manage for this purpose).

How is possible recognize when a notification posted / removed is in a group? and which is the group header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't the possibility to achieve this only with StatusBarNotification. But is possible to do something with onNotificationRemoved/Posted & getActiveNotifications.